# TSQL bypass column on update

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking for a way to bypass the update of a column on update (for the PK). All that because i need to run the script on 2 different DB. 1 has the ID as PK while the other doesn't.
So if I run:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] SET
[ID]=1
[Name]='Test'
WHERE [RealUniqueIdentifier] = N'0018b972-914c-478f-8b5c-c5abdf0e47ea'
```

EDIT as asked:

the Central DB has no PK but the [RealUniqueIdentifier] column is a uniqueidentifier and inserted automatically.

the remote DBs:
[ID] is a PK
[RealUniqueIdentifier] column is a uniqueidentifier and inserted automatically but is identical across the DBs.

So on the first DB, i will get "Cannot update identity column 'ID'."

I'm looking for a way to run the update and in the case it's a PK, then not update the column ID but still update the column [Name]

Do you know if there is any way to achieve this?

Thank you

FloD

Comment: I'm confused on this. Why don't you put the `[ID]=1` in the `Where` clause?

Comment: can you add an example of the difference in table structure between the two dbs that have this table?  It will make your question easier to answer.

Comment: So, 1 database is a central database (the one where the ID is not a PK) and multiple databases are on remote computers (where ID is a PK). The ID may be different between the remote databases since it's a PK. As a disclaimer i didn't designed the DB and can't modify them otherwise the customers applications will break